# Exponents inequality

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the next problem:

For which values of $n\in(1,\infty)$ does $x^n\leq n^x$ for all $x\in (1,\infty)$?

I expressed the two sides of the inequality as $e^{n\ln (x)}\leq e^{x\ln (n)}$. Since $e$ is strictly increasing, $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\leq \frac{\ln (n)}{n}$ but I don't know where to go from there.

Am I taking the right aproach to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good. Now ask where the maximum of  $\frac{\log y}{y}$ is attained.

Comment: Ok, I checking the derivative, the maximum is at $e$, so now I have $

Comment: You do not make it clear that you now know there is a single $n$ that works,  $n=e$.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted that before finishing it: Ok, I checking the derivative, the maximum is at $e$, so now I have $\frac{ln(x)}{x}\leq \frac{ln(n)}{n} \leq e$, is that correct? But I can't find a way to express $a$ in terms of $e$

Comment: Oh, I see, I was rambling with the inequalities

Comment: The maximum **value** of $\frac{\log y}{y}$ is unimportant here. It happens to be $1/e$.